# How shutdown feature can be enabled in SpringBoot Admin UI?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to monitor my spring boot application, which has actuator support.
And to be able to set a SpringBootAdmin server and client.
I enabled the shutdown endpoint in the client application by adding the
following to the application.properties file:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics,loggers,httptrace,shutdown
```

Now I am able to hit the actuator shutdown api through the postman client and functionality is working fine.

Is there any way to get the shut down feature/tab in the spring boot admin UI?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, even 2 years later this is still not supported. You can list it inside management.endpoints.web.exposure.include as:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown
```

It will show up, but there is no option to action it.